# Break loop from a block in a task

Tags: toit

So i have code similar to this i want to run:

```
main:

  // This works
  mloop :
    print "test"
    return
    
  //This will not compile
  task:: mloop :
     print "test"
     return //this seems t be the problem
    
mloop [block]:
  while true:
    sleep --ms=100
    block.call
```

I want to break the infinite loop from within the block. But i also need to run the loop in a task. It will not compile and gives the error message  `Can't explicitly return from within a lambda`. This does not seem like it is posible with `return` or `continue`. Is there any way a similar funtionality can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current iteration of the language. You would want to use `break.mloop` to break out of the loop:

```
main:
  task:: mloop:
    print "test"
    break.mloop // Read as "break out of mloop".

mloop [block]:
  while true: ...
```

However, this functionality isn't implemented in the compiler yet.

You have a few options to work around this:

1. Create the lambda that is passed to the task in a function:

```
task_function:
  mloop:
    print "test"
    return

main:
  task:: task_function
```

This always works.

2. Use the block's return value to signal an exit.

```
my_mloop [block]:
  mloop:
    if block.call: return

main:
  task:: my_mloop:
    print "test"
    true  // Signal end.
```

The latter has the advantage that the block's code would be inside `main` and could thus share variables more easily. It only works if the `mloop` function doesn't expect a value from the given block.

Comment: Thank you for both suggestions! solution 1. will work for my application, while solution 2 won't work as the loop i'm calling is from a Toit package and would prefer to just keep using that.